# Interaction between pipes, execvpe, and shell scripts

Tags: c, linux, shell, posix

I have the following code that forks and execvpe's a shell script and redirects its STDERR and STDOUT to the parent process.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFLEN 65536

int main () {
  int pipes[2];
  pipe(pipes);
  pid_t pid = fork();
  if (pid == -1) {return 1;}
  else if (pid > 0) {
    close(pipes[1]);
    char buf[BUFLEN];
    size_t n = read(pipes[0], buf, sizeof(buf));
    int stat = 0;
    waitpid(pid, &stat, 0);
    printf("%.*s", n, buf);
  } else {
    dup2(pipes[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
    dup2(pipes[1], STDERR_FILENO);
    close(pipes[0]);
    char *const argv[] = {"sh", "test", NULL};
    execvpe(argv[0], argv, environ);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

As a minimal working example `"test"` is:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat file.txt
echo "Hello!"
echo "Goodbye!"
```

The output of the C program is the contents of `file.txt` and then the output from the echos are lost. If it's three echo statements then all of them get seen.

My best guess is that echo is a shell builtin and the shell will fork for `cat` and my pipes will be lost. In my project it seems the first command called in the script and the rest are lost.

If my assumption is correct how can I collect all the output from any and all children of what `execvpe` spawned?

Comment: You need to read in a loop until `read` returns `0` (which means the other end of the pipe was closed). Or until there's an error, of course (when `read` returns `-1`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is simply a combination of timing and not checking for EOF before stopping reading from the pipe.  If you wrap the `read()` call into a loop to read everything, all the data is read.  When the `cat` completes, the `read()` returns everything that's available.  The output from the `echo` commands is added to the pipe afterwards, but simply not read.

This code demonstrates, I believe.  Note that `execvpe()` is not POSIX standard (and not available on macOS specifically) so I used my own surrogate header `#include "execvpe.h"` and implementation `execvpe.c` to obtain an implementation of it.  Also, POSIX does not define a header that declares `environ`, so I declared it too.  You're probably using Linux and the system headers there fix some gaps that POSIX leaves as holes.

Here's working code and data.

#### `pipe17.c`

```
/* SO 6412-3757 */
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUFLEN 65536

#include "execvpe.h"    /* execvpe() is not in POSIX */
extern char **environ;  /* No POSIX header declares environ */

int main(void)
{
    int pipes[2];
    pipe(pipes);
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (pid > 0)
    {
        close(pipes[1]);
        char buffer[BUFLEN];
        char *b_str = buffer;
        size_t b_len = sizeof(buffer);
        size_t t_len = 0;
        ssize_t n_len;
        while (b_len > 0 && (n_len = read(pipes[0], b_str, b_len)) > 0)
        {
            b_str += n_len;
            b_len -= n_len;
            t_len += n_len;
        }
        close(pipes[0]);
        int status = 0;
        int corpse = waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
        printf("%d 0x%.4X: [[%.*s]]\n", corpse, status, (int)t_len, buffer);
    }
    else
    {
        dup2(pipes[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        dup2(pipes[1], STDERR_FILENO);
        close(pipes[0]);
        close(pipes[1]);
        char *argv[] = {"sh", "test", NULL};
        execvpe(argv[0], argv, environ);
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to execute '%s'\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

#### `test`

```
#!/bin/bash
cat file.txt
echo "Hello!"
echo "Goodbye!"
echo "Errors go to standard error" >&2
```

#### `file.txt`

```
Line 1 of file1.txt
The very last line of file1.txt
```

#### Sample output

```
14171 0x0000: [[Line 1 of file1.txt
The very last line of file1.txt
Hello!
Goodbye!
Errors go to standard error
]]
```

Note that the code closes both ends of the pipe before calling `execvpe()`.  It isn't crucial here, but it often can be crucial to do so.  Your original code passed a `size_t` value, `n`, to `printf()` for use by the `*` in the format.  You might get away with that on a 64-bit machine where `sizeof(int) == sizeof(size_t)`, but it yields compilation warnings on 64-bit machines where `sizeof(int) < sizeof(size_t)`.

---

**Rule of thumb**: If you
[`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html)
one end of a pipe to standard input or standard output, close both of the
original file descriptors returned by
[`pipe()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pipe.html)
as soon as possible.
In particular, you should close them before using any of the
[`exec*()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html)
family of functions.

The rule also applies if you duplicate the descriptors with either
[`dup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup.html)
or
[`fcntl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html)
with `F_DUPFD` or `F_DUPFD_CLOEXEC`.

Comment: That's a very thorough answer and the loop was the problem in my more convoluted project code (which does pass an int to printf **phew**). And you're right the software I'm developing is specifically for Linux

Thank you!